# R8 obfuscation appears to introduce Implicit Internal Intent Vulnerability?

Tags: android-intent, android-security, android-implicit-intent

Having trouble with this security error in my pre-launch report.   I believe I have done all the work required, however this error still persists.   When I check the details, it shows be the obfuscated method that is causing the problem.   If I try and use retrace and mapping.txt, it's not found.

What is perhaps most disturbing, is what I push a build to my internal test track with the following gradle settings changed, the error disappears.

With Error:
minifyEnabled true
shrinkResources true
Without Error:
minifyEnabled false
shrinkResources false

It appears that the act of shrinking and minify INTRODUCES the error, and that my codebase is actually OK.    I'm really struggling to know how to move on from here.  I don't really want to publsh public builds without these build features, but I also can't release with the pre-launch issue.

[Overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTqXC.png)
[Issue Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ws3EO.png)

Comment: I think the best way forward here will be to file an issue on the R8 issue tracker at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=326788. One question though: Have you tried to upload an `aab` to Play built with `minifyEnabled false` to see the pre-launch report for that? You should be able to find the mapping file in `app/build/outputs/mapping/release/mapping.txt`. If you look on the right hand side of class mappings you should be able to find `m9.p$b.a` and see from where it originates.

Answer (score 0):

Got to the bottom of this. It appears R8 was (correctly) striping an intent receiver that wasn't being used, which in turn raised the play store security report.

Now I better understand the issue, I entirely removed the intent and switched to using EventBus messages (which my app already used), and ditched the intent.